# What is the distance of Venus and Uranus from the Sun?

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, mathematical-physics

The average distances x from Mercury, Earth, Mars and Jupiter to Sun are accordingly 57.9, 149.6, 227.9 and 778.3 million km. Also, their rotation periods p around the Sun are accordingly 87.960, 365.25, 687.00 and 4337.0 days.

**Formula used**: $p=kx^a$, where $p$ is the rotation period in days, $a$ is the rise (for a line between two points), $x$ is the distance from the Sun to the planet in millions of kilometers and $k$ is the ordinate value.

What is the distance x for Venus and Uranus from the Sun, if the rotation periods p around the Sun are accordingly 224.7 and 30739 days.

I noticed that the distance and period graph is exponential, but I can't seem to find a way how to calculate the x for Venus and Uranus, by using the given formula. Any ideas?

EDIT: $k$ is the ordinate value and $a$ is the rise (for a line between two points)

Comment: What's stopping you from solving this yourself? This will help us help you :-)

Comment: According to Kepler's law, the distance-period graph is *not* exponential.

Comment: @Simply Beautiful Art I tried solving it by finding k and a first, but since the graphs for distance and rotation period are exponential, then the values k and a should not be constant, thus it would not get me any closer to solving my problem. Therefore I'm out of ideas what to do next. Also, did you see my edit?

Comment: @G. Sassatelli So you are saying that k and a are both constants?

Comment: Yes, $k$ and $a$ are both constants.

Comment: It turns out that $k$ depends slightly on the mass of the planet, but that contribution can be ignored due to the mass of the Sun being way larger than the masses of planets (and in fact Kepler himself could not observe it at the time he formulated his three laws).

Comment: Please use Mathjax/LaTeX syntax in your post to typeset mathematical expressions.

Comment: @MrYouMath Sorry, I just joined this foorum. Could you remove the negatiive rating because of one "to the power of sign" and some italics? The question itself was valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason you're having issues solving the problem is the misconception that the distance and period graph is exponential, whereas it is not.

By using the logarithmic rules, you can find the values **k** and**a**  (both constants), and therefore find the distances you are looking for.